# Switch fragment without destroy previous one?

Tags: android

i'm using a navigation drawer to switch between fragments , each time i move to a new one ,it's completely recreated and the previous one is completely destroyed, so i want to conserve the state of fragments while swapping and back again

```
Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
            Fragment fragment=getHomeFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment,CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }
    };


    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
   }
```

and the getHomeFragment() :

```
     public Fragment getHomeFragment() {

    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            BoiteRFragment boiteRFragment = new BoiteRFragment();
            return boiteRFragment;
        case 2:
            InfoPersFragment infoPersFragment = new InfoPersFragment();
            return infoPersFragment;
        case 3:
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:

            PrametresFragment prametresFragment = new PrametresFragment();
            return prametresFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}
```